# Using outer query result in a subquery in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, correlated-subquery

I have two tables `points` and `contacts` and I'm trying to get the average `points.score` per contact grouped on a monthly basis.  **Note** that points and contacts aren't related, I just want the sum of points created in a month divided by the number of contacts that existed in that month.

So, I need to sum points grouped by the created_at month, and I need to take the count of contacts FOR THAT MONTH ONLY.  It's that last part that's tricking me up.  I'm not sure how I can use a column from an outer query in the subquery.  I tried something like this:

```
SELECT SUM(score) AS points_sum,
  EXTRACT(month FROM created_at) AS month,
  date_trunc('MONTH', created_at) + INTERVAL '1 month' AS next_month,
  (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM contacts WHERE contacts.created_at <= next_month) as contact_count
FROM points
GROUP BY month, next_month
ORDER BY month
```

So, I'm extracting the actual month that my points are being summed, and at the same time, getting the beginning of the next_month so that I can say "Get me the count of contacts where their created at is < next_month"

But it complains that `column next_month doesn't exist`  This is understandable as the subquery knows nothing about the outer query.  Qualifying with `points.next_month` doesn't work either.

So can someone point me in the right direction of how to achieve this?

### Tables:

**Points**

```
score | created_at
10    | "2011-11-15 21:44:00.363423"
11    | "2011-10-15 21:44:00.69667" 
12    | "2011-09-15 21:44:00.773289"
13    | "2011-08-15 21:44:00.848838"
14    | "2011-07-15 21:44:00.924152"
```

**Contacts**

```
id | created_at
6  | "2011-07-15 21:43:17.534777"
5  | "2011-08-15 21:43:17.520828"
4  | "2011-09-15 21:43:17.506452"
3  | "2011-10-15 21:43:17.491848"
1  | "2011-11-15 21:42:54.759225"
```

**sum, month and next_month (without the subselect)**

```
sum | month | next_month
14  | 7     | "2011-08-01 00:00:00"
13  | 8     | "2011-09-01 00:00:00"
12  | 9     | "2011-10-01 00:00:00"
11  | 10    | "2011-11-01 00:00:00"
10  | 11    | "2011-12-01 00:00:00"
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### Edit

Now with **running sum** of contacts. My first draft used *new contacts per month*, which is obviously not what OP wants.

```
WITH c AS (
    SELECT created_at
          ,count(id) OVER (order BY created_at) AS ct
    FROM   contacts
    ), p AS (
    SELECT date_trunc('month', created_at) AS month
          ,sum(score) AS points_sum
    FROM   points
    GROUP  BY 1
    )
SELECT p.month
      ,EXTRACT(month FROM p.month) AS month_nr
      ,p.points_sum
      ,( SELECT c.ct
         FROM   c
         WHERE  c.created_at < (p.month + interval '1 month')
         ORDER  BY c.created_at DESC
         LIMIT  1) AS contacts
FROM   p
ORDER  BY 1
```

- This works for *any* number of months across the years.
- Assumes that no month is missing in the table `points`. If you want all months, including missing ones in `points`, generate a list of months with [generate_series()](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-srf.html) and LEFT JOIN to it.
- Build a running sum in a CTE with a window function.
- Both CTE are not strictly necessary - for performance and simplification only.
- Get contacts_count in a subselect.

---

Your **original form of the query** could work like this:

```
SELECT month
      ,EXTRACT(month FROM month) AS month_nr
      ,points_sum
      ,(SELECT count(*)
        FROM   contacts c
        WHERE  c.created_at < (p.month + interval '1 month')) AS contact_count
FROM   (
    SELECT date_trunc('MONTH', created_at) AS month
          ,sum(score) AS points_sum
    FROM   points p
    GROUP  BY 1
    ) p
ORDER  BY 1
```

The fix for the immediate cause of your error is to put the aggregate into a subquery. You were mixing levels in a way that is impossible.
I expect my variant to be slightly faster with big tables. Not sure about smaller tables. Would be great if you'd report back with test results.
Plus a minor fix: `<` instead of `<=`.

Comment: @brad: I guess you don't need `next_month` at all with my query?

Comment: This is *not quite* right.  I want all contacts that exist for a given month, but you're giving me the ones that were created in that month. Contacts from previously months should also be counted in the current month (ie created_at is < next_month)

Comment: ya that seems to do the trick!  Tell me, what's the order by 1 all about?

Comment: @brad: `ODER BY 1` is just a notational shorthand for `ORDER BY p.month` in this case. You can use the ordinal number of columns in the select list. I quote the [manual here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/interactive/sql-select.html): `Each expression can be the name or ordinal number of an output column (SELECT list item)`. Also: see my amended answer for more info on what was going on.

Comment: oh wow thanks.  Ya I've never even seen that type of syntax used in the first answer, the 2nd one looks a bit more familiar to me.  I'll Keep both of these on record and see which one works best!  Thanks so much, I don't think I"ve ever had such a complete answer on SO!!

Comment: @brad: Cool that you like it. :) Would be sad if all the effort was futile.

Comment: Erwin I have to thank you again.  I had never heard of Common Table Expressions until I saw this.  They're so much easier to read!  And from what I gather, can be more performant as well.  Still reading into why this is the case, but again, thanks so much!